# javafx show dialog before init

Tags: java, javafx-8, startup, launcher, preinit

I would like to know the best way to show a `dialog(Stage)` before the `init` method of the main application is called. I can't implement it in the init method because it doesn't run on the JavaFX Application Thread and when implementing it in the start method, I would loose the option of a preloader (which only exists during the init phase if I understood it correctly).

It should be something like the workspace chooser in eclipse or the catalog chooser in lightroom.

A solution I can think of is creating two programs, one starter and the main app but I would prefer it if it can happen in the same application. If it can only be done in that way, **How do I start the main *app.jar* with the same Java version as the starter was started?** (It mustn't be called with the Java version configured in the path as the command line/terminal allows one to start applications with a different version).

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The `init()` method is part of the initialization of the FX Application lifecycle: you can hardly expect to run part of your application before this is complete. Why not just show the dialog in the `start()` method, as usual, then when the dialog is dismissed do whatever processing you need before showing the main application window?

Comment: @James_D I would like to do it because the code taking enough time for a preloader/splash-screen happens after the user selection and as far as I understand, the preloaders lifecycle is during the `init()` method thus the user might wait for quite some seconds before the main app Stage appears without seeing a progress bar. This means I don't need a preloader and open a decoration less dialog as a progress indicating splash screen in the `start()` method till the main Stage can be displayed?

Comment: So you could just use the preloader mechanism. Though it's easier (imo) to show a splash screen with progress bar from the `start()` method, do whatever you are doing that takes so much time in a task in a background thread, and show the main screen when that is complete.

Comment: @James_D yes that would be my easy choice but I think it's not the best practise to do so. How could it be done using the preloader mechanism?

Comment: @Scourge I got the same demand, how did you handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Launching JavaFX applications is done through invoking the `Application.launch()`, where  `LauncherImpl#launchApplication` is called.

In the `launchApplication`, the *private* *method* `launchApplication` is called with `preloaderClass` *argument* having the following signature:

```
public static void launchApplication(final Class<? extends Application> appClass,
           final Class<? extends Preloader> preloaderClass,
           final String[] args)
```

Now the `preloader` *class* is the place where you call the **dialog**.

Just call your **dialog** and put your other *functionalities* here:

```
public class MyPreloader extends Preloader {
    private Stage preloaderStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
       this.preloaderStage = primaryStage;

       VBox loading = new VBox(20);
       loading.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
       loading.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
       loading.getChildren().add(new ProgressBar());
       loading.getChildren().add(new Label("Please wait..."));

       BorderPane root = new BorderPane(loading);
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);

       primaryStage.setWidth(800);
       primaryStage.setHeight(600);
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
   }

   @Override
   public void handleStateChangeNotification(StateChangeNotification   
       stateChangeNotification) {

       if (stateChangeNotification.getType() == Type.BEFORE_START) {
           preloaderStage.hide();
       } 
   }
}
```

And then pass it to the `launchApplication`*method*.

***`And just perfect!`***
***`Enjoy!`***

Comment: Thank you for your response so far, but I actually don't understand how it should be done. I mean the dialog should appear even before the main app get initilized (thus before the Preloader gets displayed), because the user action in that dialog should set an important variable for the init-method or even cancel the whole startup.

Or a question regarding your idea: When I should put it in the preloader, how do I get the init method to wait for the user input to continue initializing and still showing the preloader "splash screen" with progress?

Comment: But you have the Stage object in your disposal no?

Comment: Yes, I have it but the remaining question is how do I block the main apps `init()` method from running before the user made the selection?
A different approach by implementing the user selection, splash screen and loading in the `start()` method of the main app is possible but would result in a bit less cleaner structure.